# Lotus Domino as Amazon IAM Identity Provider

Tags: ibm-domino, amazon-iam, openid, federated

I am looking for the way to configure our corporate Lotus Domino server as an Idenity Provider of Amazon IAM service. Amazon supports SAML and OpenID Provider Types. Can I configure Domino server that way? Otherwise, are there other ways to configure Lotus Domino to be an Identity Provider of Amazon?

Answer (score 0):

Domino is not a Identity Provider. You'll have to implement this on your own.